# BeautifulSoup HTTPResponse has no attribute encode

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urlopen

I'm trying to get beautifulsoup working with a URL, like the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://proxies.org")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.encode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

However, I am getting a error:

```
 File "c:\Python3\ProxyList.py", line 3, in <module>
    html = urlopen("http://proxies.org").encode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any idea why? Could it be to do with the urlopen function? Why is it needing the utf-8?

There clearly seems to be some differences with Python 3 and BeautifulSoup4, regarding the examples that are given (which seem to be out of date or wrong now)...

Comment: This ended up being the solution that was needed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382686/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-u2010-character-m

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `urlopen` returns a HTTPResponse object and you were treating that as straight HTML. You need to chain the `.read()` method on the response in order to get the HTML:

```
response = urlopen("http://proxies.org")
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
print (soup.find_all('a'))
```

You probably also want to use `html.decode("utf-8")` rather than `html.encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: Hi Josh, this is still not working for me, Im using exactly the same code as you and its giving me a "character maps to <undefined>" error

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().encode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://proxies.org")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

1. First, `urlopen` will return a file-like object
2. `BeautifulSoup` can accept file-like object and decode it automatically, you should not worry about it.

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup):

To parse a document, pass it into the BeautifulSoup constructor. **You can pass in a string or an open filehandle**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>data</html>")
```

**First, the document is converted to Unicode, and HTML entities are converted to Unicode characters**