# How to extract h1 tag from an HTML file with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'am trying to extract the h1(or any header) header from an HTML file.

My python code is as below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.le.ac.uk/oerresources/bdra/html/page_09.htm');
# print(html.read());

# using beautifulsoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser');
h2 = bs.find('h2', {'id' : 'toc'});
print(bs.find_all(["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]));
print(h2);
```

As you can see from the above snippet i have tried to extract all the headers but all i get is an empty list and None. I have checked the `html` file for headers and i have verified that they are present. I have also tried using dictionary like `h2 = bs.find('h2', {'class' : 'toc'});`

Can somebody tell me what is that i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What version are you using, it works form me: `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`. I can hind `h1` and `h2`. There isn't any h2 with id=toc.

Comment: I installed bs4

Comment: The latest version? Type `pip freeze`, it will show the version.

Comment: @AndrejKesely beautifulsoup4==4.6.0 is what it shows

Comment: That's old version. Update it to `4.7.1`. Because the code works for me (I'm on Python 3.6.8)

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have updated both bs and python to 4.7.1 and 3.7 respectively. Still i didn't get the correct output.

Comment: That's strange, because when I run the exact code you posted here I get `[<h1>Introduction to HTML/XHTML</h1>, <h2><a href="index.htm" id="toc-title">Table of Contents</a></h2>, <h2>Example HTML Document</h2>]` and `None`. Try using `lxml` instead of `html.parser`. Try to `print(bs.prettify())` to see what is inside the soup.

Comment: Strangely it works now. Somehow it didn't, the first time i ran it. Thanks fro the help.

Answer (score 1):

I get the following output when I run the code:

```
[<h1>Introduction to HTML/XHTML</h1>, <h2><a href="index.htm" id="toc-title">Table of Contents</a></h2>, <h2>Example HTML Document</h2>]
```

Code I used:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.le.ac.uk/oerresources/bdra/html/page_09.htm').read().decode("utf-8")
# using beautifulsoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(bs.find_all(["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]))
```

urlopen gives you a http.client.HTTPResponse object you need to read that and then decode it to UTF-8.

This quesiton is probably a copy of -[BeautifulSoup HTTPResponse has no attribute encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925548/beautifulsoup-httpresponse-has-no-attribute-encode)