# UTF-8 in AppVeyor, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-3.6, appveyor

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can use non-ascii symbols for AppVeyor builds.

---

### 2. Settings

My simple [**`SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py`**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPythonista/blob/master/SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py) file:

```python
print('Саша наилучшая!')
```

My simple [**`appveyor.yml`**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPythonista/blob/master/appveyor.yml) file:

```yaml
environment:

  matrix:

    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python36-x64"
      PYTHON_VERSION: "3.6.3"
      PYTHON_ARCH: "64"
      PIP: "C:\\Python36-x64\\Scripts\\pip"

platform: x64

build_script:

  - cmd: "%PYTHON%\\python SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py"
```

Both files I save in UTF-8 encoding.

---

### 3. Expected behavior

If I run `SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py` file in my terminal or interpreter [**SublimeREPL**](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), I get:

```shell
D:\SashaPythonista>python SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py
Саша наилучшая!
```

If my `SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py` file is not contain Cyrillic symbols:

```python
print('Sasha superior!')
```

AppVeyor build [**successful passed**](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Kristinita/sashapythonista-7l3yk/build/1.0.70):

```python
Build started
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPythonista.git C:\projects\sashapythonista-7l3yk
git checkout -qf 3a0393a5b9548a5debabebfc5e28d17f3000a768
%PYTHON%\python SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py
Sasha superior!
Discovering tests...OK
Build success
```

---

### 4. Actual behavior

[**My AppVeyor build failed**](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Kristinita/sashapythonista-7l3yk/build/1.0.69):

```python
Build started
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPythonista.git C:\projects\sashapythonista-7l3yk
git checkout -qf 262cef287d45b1548640b9a773b680de90b7d138
%PYTHON%\python SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py", line 1, in <module>
    print('\u0421\u0430\u0448\u0430 \u043d\u0430\u0438\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0448\u0430\u044f!')
  File "C:\Python36-x64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
Command exited with code 1
```

---

### 5. Not helped

1. I add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in top of `SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py` file,
2. I [**add `chcp 65001`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383309/5951529) command to `appveyor.yml` file,
3. I [**install `win-unicode-console`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/5951529) to `appveyor.yml` file,

My updated `SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py` file:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print('Саша наилучшая!')
```

My updated `appveyor.yml` file:

```yaml
environment:

  matrix:

    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python36-x64"
      PYTHON_VERSION: "3.6.3"
      PYTHON_ARCH: "64"
      PIP: "C:\\Python36-x64\\Scripts\\pip"

platform: x64

install:

  - cmd: "%PIP% install win-unicode-console"
  - cmd: chcp 65001

build_script:

  - cmd: "%PYTHON%\\python SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py"
```

My [**updated AppVeyor build**](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Kristinita/sashapythonista-7l3yk/build/1.0.73):

```python
Build started
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPythonista.git C:\projects\sashapythonista-7l3yk
git checkout -qf 11df07d4c424cd8e28a1b0db0f43906aa63f42f1
Running Install scripts
%PIP% install win-unicode-console
Collecting win-unicode-console
  Downloading win_unicode_console-0.5.zip
Installing collected packages: win-unicode-console
  Running setup.py install for win-unicode-console: started
    Running setup.py install for win-unicode-console: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed win-unicode-console-0.5
chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
%PYTHON%\python SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SashaAppVeyorEncoding.py", line 2, in <module>
    print('\u0421\u0430\u0448\u0430 \u043d\u0430\u0438\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0448\u0430\u044f!')
  File "C:\Python36-x64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
Command exited with code 1
```

---

### 6. Local environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**Python:**
3.6.3
**chcp:**
Active code page: 65001

Comment: It seems the output is redirected. Try `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` envvar. Unrelated: 1- you don't need `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in Python 3 (it is default) 2- you don't need win-unicode-console on Python 3.6 (sys.stdout uses Unicode API when writing to the console) 3- you don't need `chcp 65001` (it may be harmful) the Unicode API works regardless chcp value. Just configure the font in the console. See [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419)

Comment: @jfs: move `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` as answer, that I can to raise your reputation. It help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `python` doesn't print to the console on AppVeyor -- the output is redirected. Therefore [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) is used to encode Unicode text to bytes while printing to stdout. `cp1252` supports only a few from a million of Unicode characters. To change `sys.stdout.encoding` here, you could [`set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` envvar](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) -- utf-8 character encoding supports all Unicode characters.

Comment: makes sense, any idea how to get this to work with a frozen python app ? Tried it in our appveyor pipeline but it's not working.

Comment: @Overdrivr you can test locally on what happens in your case just by redirecting the output to a file: `app.exe > output.txt`