# Python BeautifulSoup error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.quikr.com/jobs/direct-hiring-for-fresher-b.tech-diploma-iti-for-maruti-suzuki-gurgaon-W0QQAdIdZ293462666"
encode = 'utf-8'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "close",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
encodeData = response.text.encode(encode)
soup = BeautifulSoup(encodeData)
print soup.prettify()
```

I am trying to scrap a html page, this is very basic code. But still I am getting error when I use `prettify()`

error is

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 7

Comment: I tried to run your code and it works completely fine(py2, py3 both)

Comment: I don't know, I am still getting the error. However after removing prettify() it working fine.

Comment: can you tell which platform you are running?

Comment: Windows Seems like everything is working except prettify()

Comment: sorry i can't help you then, i am a linux guy and don't have windows.

Comment: Setting the encoding to utf-8 might work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382686/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-u2010-character-m

Comment: What version of python are you using? I've tested your code on Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.2 and it works OK.

Comment: If it really is just `prettify` that's giving you grief then replace that line with a construction that calls `BeautifulSoup` with something like this: `BeautifulSoup(response.text.encode(encode, 'replace')`. Bizarre characters will be cheerfully ignored.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem. The issue probably isn't with your code, but with whatever console you're printing to. [Beautifulsoup uses a unicode encoding](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit), which a lot of editors don't always play nice with (for example, i get this error a lot when I print a soup in Sublime Text). Encoding the string to another format (UTF-8, ascii) should do the trick.

```
print soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')
```

I haven't tested, that may just fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks all Seems like this is a environment issue. In my linux it's working fine.