# Error getting ancestor web element attributes

Tags: c#, python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a method to get an ancestor element of a web_element:

```
def find_ancestor(self, name):
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_name(name)
    ancestor = element.find_element_by_xpath("ancestor::*")
    print(ancestor)
    attr = ancestor.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    print(attr)
```

The output for `print(ancestor)` is `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="43f99228044a37dab999a9512b5e268e", element="0.22129539497775563-3")>`
When I try to access and print attributes I get an error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 292: character maps to <undefined>`
The top of my script has `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*`  What am I missing/doing wrong? My feeling is 'ancestor' returns differently than other xpath axes!?

**background/bonus help**
Ideally, I want methods to get parent, preceding-sibling, following-sibling etc.
But when I try such actions on a table cell `preceding-sibling` is not getting the previous cell (no element found), and with `parent` I am getting back the same element (the same table cell and not table row).
I am showing python but don't mind answers in c#.

Comment: Shouldn't your xpath have `/` in it? Have you tried `//*[name="foo"]/parent::*` , what does this give you?

Comment: @nilesh makes no difference.  The xpath I have is returning an element as it does if I use an xpath as you described.  My understanding is that you don't have to have slashes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I changed the last line to `print(attr.encode("utf-8"))`
which works.  I don't get why that is required when I have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*` at the top of my script. But I am now seeing the ancestor.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382686/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-u2010-character-m